# Need help on a trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

The question is-
Points D and E divide equal sides AC and AB of an equilateral triangle ABC according to the
ratio of :  = :  = : . Edges BD and CE meet at point O. Find ∠.

So, when I tried it, I have found out the following angles.

∠ACE= 40, ∠CDB=80, ∠COB=120, ∠COD=60, 
∠ODA= 100,∠AEO=80 (I don't know how to put in the degree symbol)
However, I can't seen to find the angle which is actually required. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found $\angle OCA= \angle ACE=40$

Consider the triangle $AOC$

Note that $\angle AOC = 180-\angle OCA-\angle OAC=180-40-30 =110$

Comment: Thank you,but how do you know angle OAC is 30?

Comment: $60/2=30$ using the fact that the triangle is equilateral